# Character does not "see" the player (3D Game)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am following [this](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/enemies-part-1-static-observers?projectId=5caf65ddedbc2a08d53c7acb#5caf8c03edbc2a0c0aee434f) unity 3D course. I followed every single step of the part called "Enemies Part 1: Static Observers", and after re-checking the code and doing researches for a day, I still did not find the problem. The scope of this part of the tutorial is to make that when the "Gargoyle" sees the player, when passing in front of him, should restart the game.

These are the two scripts that should make this work, but don't.

Observer (Gargoyle):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Observer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public GameEnding gameEnding;
    bool m_IsPlayerInRange;

    void OnTriggerEvent(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.transform == player)
        {
            m_IsPlayerInRange = true;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.transform == player)
        {
            m_IsPlayerInRange = false;
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (m_IsPlayerInRange)
        {
            Vector3 direction = player.position - transform.position + Vector3.up;
            Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, direction);
            RaycastHit raycastHit;

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out raycastHit))
            {
                if (raycastHit.collider.transform == player)
                {
                    gameEnding.CaughtPlayer();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the GameEnding script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameEnding : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float fadeDuration = 1f;
    public float displayImageDuration = 1f;
    public GameObject player;
    public CanvasGroup exitBackgroundImageCanvasGroup;
    public CanvasGroup caughtBackgroundImageCanvasGroup;

    bool m_IsPlayerAtExit;
    bool m_IsPlayerCaught;
    float m_Timer;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject == player)
        {
            m_IsPlayerAtExit = true;
        }
    }

    public void CaughtPlayer()
    {
        m_IsPlayerCaught = true;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (m_IsPlayerAtExit)
        {
            EndLevel(exitBackgroundImageCanvasGroup, false);
        }
        else if (m_IsPlayerCaught)
        {
            EndLevel(caughtBackgroundImageCanvasGroup, true);
        }
    }

    void EndLevel(CanvasGroup imageCanvasGroup, bool doRestart)
    {
        m_Timer += Time.deltaTime;

        imageCanvasGroup.alpha = m_Timer / fadeDuration;

        if (m_Timer > fadeDuration + displayImageDuration)
        {
            if (doRestart)
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
            }
            else
            {
                Application.Quit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Back to the unity editor, I set the variables (player, gameending, exitimagebackground and caught imagebackground.

Does anybody know what the problem is and could help me out?

Thank you!

Edit: 
these are the components of the Player Character:
[image]

and these of the Gargoyle:

[image: and these of the Gargoyle:]

Which has these as children:

[image]

which have these other components:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you include what components the Player and observer currently have in the inspector? More specifically, does the player and observer have rigidybody and collider?

Comment: @Kaynn yes thank you, I added them in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your `Observer` class,

```
void OnTriggerEvent(Collider other)
{
    if (other.transform == player)
    {
        m_IsPlayerInRange = true;
    }
}
```

The function name `is OnTriggerEvent(Collider)`, it should be `OnTrigger**Enter**(Collider)` instead.
Otherwise, it should work as intended.